# Delete worksheets in another workbook and close

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks. Let call them wb1 and wb2. All my code resides in wb1. As part of the code in wb1, I would like to delete some worksheets in wb2, close wb2, and then continue my code in wb1.

My problem is that when I delete the worksheets in wb2 I have now activated wb2 and stopped the code in wb1 from running.

Does any have experience with this? Are there any workarounds?

When I run the below, the execution stops after deleting wsControl. I get stuck at wsTables.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsControl As Worksheet, wsTables As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsControl = wb.Sheets("Control")
Set wsTables = wb.Sheets("Tables")

wsControl.Delete
wsTables.Delete

wb.Close True
```

Thank you!

Comment: Activating a second workbook doesn't stop VBA from executing in the first workbook.  Whatever problem you're having would be easier to figure out if you posted the code you're using, along with a description of exactly what happens when you run it.

Comment: I added the code. thank you

Comment: Do you get an error message?  Do you have other sheets in `wb`, or just those two? (You can't delete **all** the sheets in a workbook.)  Is the ActiveWorkbook the one you call wb1 or wb2?

Comment: I don't get an error message. The code just stops running. The ActiveWorkbook is wb2.

Comment: You say the code just stops running - is that even when you are stepping through the code using F8 to execute one statement at a time?  So after pressing F8 on the `wsControl.Delete` line, the macro stops, both wb1 and wb2 are still open, and wb2's Sheets("Tables") still exists?  Does wb2's Sheets("Control") still exist?

Comment: This question is old, but I have the same issue.  deletion of the first worksheet works and then macro stops. (I have several worksheets).  I think the issue is that delete the worksheet is moving the "focus" to the other workbook and stopping the macro.  I currently have no solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Application.DisplayAlerts=False` to suppress the delete confirmation message Excel otherwise shows.